# How to use QStackedWidget()

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Am trying to use QStackedWidget() to switch to my next window but when i do that i get some errors that don't have when i run my ".py" files separately.

what my app should do is ... activate my group box with a click, then if i click the button, a new transparent window should pop-up with a mouse-cross listener, then when you click something it should stops returning the mouse cursor to normal and closing the transparent window.

window1.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QKeySequence, QIcon, QCursor
from window2 import *

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Form, self).__init__()

    ##if i use this method, it does not show my transparent window, also it shows an error that i dont get when run it separately.

    def goToTransparentWindowMethod(self):
        self.goToTransparentWindow = TransparentWindowClass()
        myWindow.addWidget(self.goToTransparentWindow)
        myWindow.setCurrentIndex(myWindow.currentIndex()+1)

    def setupUi(self, myWindow):
        myWindow.setObjectName("myWindow")
        myWindow.resize(627, 327)

        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(myWindow)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 300, 270))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.gpb_main = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.gpb_main.setCheckable(True)
        self.gpb_main.setChecked(False)
        self.gpb_main.setObjectName("gpb_spell_main")

        self.btn_main = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gpb_main)
        self.btn_main.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 88, 27))
        self.btn_main.setObjectName("btn_main")
        self.btn_main.clicked.connect(self.goToTransparentWindowMethod)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.gpb_main)

        self.retranslateUi(myWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(myWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, myWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        myWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("myWindow", "Window1"))
        self.gpb_main.setTitle(_translate("myWindow", "example"))
        self.btn_main.setText(_translate("myWindow", "click me"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(myWindow)
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

window2.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import pyautogui


class TransparentWindowThreadClass(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TransparentWindowThreadClass, self).__init__()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_click_main(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        try:
            if pressed:
                self.pos_main = pyautogui.position()
                self.get_rgb_main = pyautogui.pixel(self.pos_main[0], self.pos_main[1])
                r = self.get_rgb_main.red
                g = self.get_rgb_main.green
                b = self.get_rgb_main.blue
                self.get_rgb_main = r,g,b

                Transparent_Window.unsetCursor()#error here when is called from window1
                Transparent_Window.close()#error here when is called from window1
             
                #Pressed
                self.pressed_Msg = 'Pressed at x:{0}  y:{1} RGB:{2}'.format(x, y, self.get_rgb_main)
                print(self.pressed_Msg)
            else: 
                #Released msg
                self.released_Msg = 'Released at x:{0} y:{1} RGB:{2}'.format(x, y, self.get_rgb_main)
                print(self.released_Msg)

            if not pressed:
                return False

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('you pressed ctrl+c')
        except NameError:
            print("Error on_click_main")
        except RuntimeError:
            print('run time error')
        except TypeError:
            print('ype error')
        except AttributeError:
            print('Attribute Error')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def loop_onclick_listener(self):
        try:
            with Listener(on_click=self.on_click_main) as listener:             
                listener.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('you pressed ctrl+c')
        except NameError:
            print("Error onclick_listener")
        except RuntimeError:
            print('run time error')
        except TypeError:
            print('ype error')
        except AttributeError:
            print('Attribute Error')

class TransparentWindowClass(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TransparentWindowClass, self).__init__()

        self.monitorResolution = pyautogui.size()

        # create a QThread and start the thread that handles
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.thread.start()

        # create the worker without a parent so you can move it
        self.worker = TransparentWindowThreadClass()## my custom thread class
        # the worker is moved to another thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        # if the thread started, connect it
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.loop_onclick_listener)


    def setupUi(self, Transparent_Window):
        Transparent_Window.setObjectName("Transparent_Window")
        Transparent_Window.resize(self.monitorResolution[0], self.monitorResolution[1])
        Transparent_Window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        Transparent_Window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        Transparent_Window.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor))

        self.retranslateUi(Transparent_Window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Transparent_Window)

    def retranslateUi(self, Transparent_Window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Transparent_Window.setWindowTitle(_translate("Transparent", "Transparent Window"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Transparent_Window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = TransparentWindowClass()
    ui.setupUi(Transparent_Window)
    Transparent_Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I see a lot of bad choices here, starting from the fact that you're trying to edit/merge pyuic generated code (which is largely considered a terrible practice, other than clearly discouraged by their own header comments). Besides, can you please clarify why are you using pyinput and pyautogui?

Comment: Hi, am using a pyinput for the listener and pyautogui to get the pixels easier. sorry

Comment: That is not a sufficient explanation, I know what those module do, I asked *why* you use them, instead of what Qt already provides.

Comment: Hi @musicamantex about the Listener is because i need to get the position on my screen, does not matter if it is on my transparent window widget or outside of it, for pyautogui ... am using it to get the screen monitor size with not restricted areas, and also get the pixel color of my x,y position (inside or outside a widget and not restricted areas). if you have a suggestion, please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things too complex.

Also, even assuming that no other possible solution could be used, you must remember that widgets are **not** thread-safe, and can not be directly accessed from external threads. The only safe and correct way to communicate between threads is by using signals and slots.

That said, there is no need for pyautogui nor pynput if you just want to get the color of a pixel on the screen.

If you want to grab a pixel on the screen, you can use the QScreen function [`grabWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow), using 0 as window id (which matches the whole screen), and with a single-pixel area.

Then you can use [`grabMouse()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse) to ensure that you always receive mouse events, even if the mouse is outside of the widget and no mouse button was being pressed. Note that `grabMouse()` can only work on visible widgets, so we need to "hide" the window by moving it off-screen.

Then, overriding `mousePressEvent()` you can use `grabWindow()` with the global position of the mouse, it will return a QPixmap that can be converted to a QImage and get the [`pixelColor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixelColor) of the grab above.

The grabbing can be canceled by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class GrabTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(200, 200)

        self.button = QPushButton('Grab!')

        self.colorLabel = QLabel('No color', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.colorLabel.setFixedSize(120, 30)
        self.colorLabel.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid black;')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.colorLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addStretch()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.startGrab)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if QWidget.mouseGrabber() == self:
            self.getPixel(event.globalPos())
        else:
            super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if QWidget.mouseGrabber() == self and event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.stopGrab()
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def startGrab(self):
        self.grabMouse(Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.oldPos = self.pos()
        deskRect = QRect()
        for screen in QApplication.screens():
            deskRect |= screen.geometry()
        # move the window off screen while keeping it visible
        self.move(deskRect.bottomRight())


    def stopGrab(self):
        self.releaseMouse()
        self.move(self.oldPos)

    def getPixel(self, pos):
        screen = QApplication.screens()[0]
        pixmap = screen.grabWindow(0, pos.x(), pos.y(), 1, 1)
        color = pixmap.toImage().pixelColor(0, 0)
        if color.lightnessF() > .5:
            textColor = 'black'
        else:
            textColor = 'white'
        self.colorLabel.setStyleSheet('''
            color: {};
            background: {};
        '''.format(textColor, color.name()))
        self.colorLabel.setText(color.name())
        self.stopGrab()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    grabber = GrabTest()
    grabber.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the info, it helps a lot but one of the reasons why i need a transparent window covering my 2 or 3 screens is because i want to avoid moving or selecting something on my screen, do u have any recommendation?. Finally ... because widgets are not thread-safe, whats do you recommend to run 5 loops simultaneously, what am trying to do is open a transparent window then my 5 loops are going to look for specific pixel colors that i picked before and then do something, thanks

Comment: You cannot have a "transparent" (translucent) widget inside an opaque window. You have to make the top level window with translucent background and then make all widgets that are not "see through" with an opaque background. Otherwise, don't use QStackedWidget (and certainly don't create new instances of the same class every time, as that's not how QStackedWidget works). That said, python prevent concurrency, so there's really no benefit in using separate threads for *computation* (not one, nor 5), as you will have absolutely *no* improvement from that. On the contrary, it could be even worse.

Comment: so am a little confused, I should set my window1 opacity to 0 and then return to normal to achieve my transparent window?, about the threads I need 5 loops running at the same time, how can I achieve this if it is not with threads?, sorry and thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. If you want "general" transparency, that *must* be set on the top level widget, and then override the background of the containers that you don't want as transparent (normally set with the [`autoFillBackground`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property); unfortunately, your question is too vague for this kind of issue, so I can't really help you much more on this: my answer conceptually *did* solve your question as it was asked; 2. as said, python doesn't allow concurrency. I strongly suggest you to do more research about the difference between threads and processes.

Comment: ok, understood ... I will research more about their differences, i will mark this post as solved, thank you so much for your help.